# accessing highlighted/selected text

Tags: jquery, html, css

When a user highlights a section of the web page being, how do I get access to the piece of html or text that a user has selected.

Looks like the [jquery select](http://api.jquery.com/select/) only works on input elements.

Basically what is the easy way to access parts where the css3 [::selection](http://%22http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_selection.asp) selector has taken effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/jquery-get-the-highlighted-text

Comment: I think there is already a solution posted  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse   
Try to observe others question and answers first then only post the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
document.getSelection()

var text = '';
if (window.getSelection)
    {
        text = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection)
    {
        text = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    else return;
```